# Retornar 2 valores desde un método asincrónico

Tags: c#, xamarin

Tengo un proyecto *xamarin android*, que en una `view` genera el mapa de *google api*, se logro exitosamente ubicar una ubicación siempre y cuando se le asigne la longitud y latitud explicitamente en una variable, el problema esta en cuanto se desea que tome estos datos desde la posición actual vía gps, implemente un plugin de *xamarin* que cumple con obtener estos 2 valores, pero usa un método asincronico y no encuentro la manera de que devuelva estos 2 valores, les comparto el código.

```
public class RayMapActivity : Activity
{
    private Button externalMapButton;
    private FrameLayout mapFrameLayout;
    private MapFragment mapFragment;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private LatLng rayLocation;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //rayLocation = new LatLng(50.846704, 4.352446); asignando los valores explicitamente si funciona

        Localizar();

        rayLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.RayMapView);

        FindViews();

        HandleEvents();

        CreateMapFragment();

        UpdateMapView();  // este metodo usa los valores de raylocation 

    }
```

dentro de la misma clase, esta el metodo.

```
private async void Localizar()
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current; // linea de acceso a la API
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

        if (locator.IsGeolocationAvailable) // devuelve si el servicio existe en la aplicacion
        {
            if (locator.IsGeolocationEnabled) // si el gps esta activado
            {
                if (!locator.IsListening)
                {
                    await locator.StartListeningAsync(5, 3000);
                }

                locator.PositionChanged += (cambio, args) =>
                {
                    var loc = args.Position; 
                    latitude = loc.Latitude; // si recibe la Latitude correcta
                    longitude = loc.Longitude; // si recibe la Longitude correcta
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

cree esas 2 variables *double* para confirmar que los valores si se obtenían correctamente, y con punto de ruptura vi que si los obtenía y almacenaba.

Comment: No hay un evento parecido a "locator.ListeningEnds" ? para que llames ahi tus variables una vez la escucha termina, o simplemente quita el awaiter y llama el metodo .Wait(), asi no obtendras valores nulos al no esperar que termine la escucha, si usaras Wait() te aconsejo que metas en un nuevo hilo tus if(!locator.IsLetning) y locator.PositionChanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esperaremos que el método asicronico termine para asegurarnos de que los valores asignados en el evento PositionChanged no sean nulos, podrías hacerlo dentro de otro hilo si no quieres que el resto de código espere por ellos.

```
    if (locator.IsGeolocationAvailable) // devuelve si el servicio existe en la aplicacion
    {
        if (locator.IsGeolocationEnabled) // si el gps esta activado
        {
            new Thread(()=> //De esta forma el codigo seguira corriendo pero solo asignara los valores cuando Listening alla terminado su trabajo
            { 
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

                if (!locator.IsListening)
                {
                    locator.StartListeningAsync(5, 3000).Wait();
                }

                locator.PositionChanged += (cambio, args) =>
                {
                    var loc = args.Position; 
                    latitude = loc.Latitude; // si recibe la Latitude correcta
                    longitude = loc.Longitude; // si recibe la Longitude correcta
                };

            }.Start());
        }
    }
}
```

Si te he entendido mal por favor aclara tu pregunta, exactamente cual es tu problema, obtienes valares nulos cuando no le haces break porque el metodo asicronico no terminaba de hacer su trabajo o no sabes como asignar los valores devuelto en PositionChanged en uno solo? la verdad no esta muy claro para mi, aun asi espero que te haya ayudado.

Podria ser tu problema algo como: var x = locator.StartListeningAsync(5, 3000); Mira el tipo que obtiene x y como usarlo.

Comment: El problema era extraer los 2 valores double que generaba el metodo asincronico, despues de intentar con task y tuple, decidi mejor llamar al otro metodo dentro del asincronico para que asi no necesitar sacar las variables fuera, gracias por tu comentario, estoy analizandolo C:

Answer (score 1):

Solucioné el problema de extraer las 2 variables double fuera del método asincrónico que las generó, dado que probé con `Task` y `Tuple<double, double>`
y no lo logré, ya que desaparecían las variables locales del método al culminar éste, hice llamado al otro método que las utilizaba y se los envío como parámetros, modificando el método, claro está.

```
private void UpdateMapView(double lat, double lon)
    {

        rayLocation = new LatLng(lat, lon);

        var mapReadyCallback = new LocalMapReady();

        mapReadyCallback.MapReady += (sender, args) =>
        {
            googleMap = (sender as LocalMapReady).Map;

            if (googleMap != null)
            {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.SetPosition(rayLocation);
                markerOptions.SetTitle("Posicion actual");
                googleMap.AddMarker(markerOptions);


                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(rayLocation, 10); // el 15 es el nivel de zoom del mapa
                googleMap.MoveCamera(cameraUpdate); // se le pide a google map mover la camara a ese lugar
            }
        };

        mapFragment.GetMapAsync(mapReadyCallback);
    }
```

En la misma clase:

```
private async void Localizar()
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current; // linea de acceso a la API
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

        if (locator.IsGeolocationAvailable) // devuelve si el servicio existe en la aplicacion
        {
            if (locator.IsGeolocationEnabled) // si el gps esta activado
            {
                if (!locator.IsListening)
                {
                    await locator.StartListeningAsync(5, 3000);
                }

                locator.PositionChanged += (cambio, args) =>
                {
                    var loc = args.Position;
                    UpdateMapView(loc.Latitude, loc.Longitude);
                };
            }
        }
    }
```